# PHP array how to merge

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have this array:

```
array(9) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) ",103,"
    [1]=>
    string(4) ",12,"
    [2]=>
    string(5) ",123,"
    [3]=>
    string(5) ",135,"
    [4]=>
    string(5) ",148,"
    [5]=>
    string(4) ",27,"
    [6]=>
    string(16) ",30,31,38,39,40,"
    [7]=>
    string(4) ",35,"
    [8]=>
    string(4) ",94,"
}
```

How can I merge it to an array like this?

```
$a = array(12, 27, 30, 31, 35, 38, 39, 40, ...)
```

I tried but got no clue...

Comment: no idea how the 2 arrays are related

Comment: So are you saying you want all the values in that array to be put into a single array, and the sorted?

Comment: Yes, Bill, thats true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution using `preg_match_all` and `sort` functions:

```
$arr = [",103,",",12,",",123,",",135,",",148,",",27,",",30,31,38,39,40,",",35,",",94,"];
preg_match_all('/\d+/', implode("", $arr), $m);
$result = $m[0];
sort($result);

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 12
    [1] => 27
    [2] => 30
    [3] => 31
    [4] => 35
    [5] => 38
    [6] => 39
    [7] => 40
    [8] => 94
    [9] => 103
    [10] => 123
    [11] => 135
    [12] => 148
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$test = array(",103,", ",12,", ",123,", ",135,", ",148,", ",27,",",30,31,38,39,40,", ",35,", ",94,");

$values = array_filter(explode(',', implode(",", $test)));
sort($values);
print_r($values);
```

- implode all the values to one string
- convert to array
- remove empty values
- sort

Will output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 12
    [1] => 27
    [2] => 30
    [3] => 31
    [4] => 35
    [5] => 38
    [6] => 39
    [7] => 40
    [8] => 94
    [9] => 103
    [10] => 123
    [11] => 135
    [12] => 148
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop over the array and then then explode it by commas. Then if the value isn't an empty sting, add it to the new array.

```
$arr = [",103,", ",12,", ",123,", ",135,", ",148,", ",27,", ",30,31,38,39,40,", ",35,", ",94,"];
$new = array();

foreach ($arr as $val) {
  foreach (explode(",", $val) as $char) {
      if ($char != '') {
        array_push($new, $char);
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
sort(explode(',', str_replace(',,', ',', implode('', $a))));
```